# AWS Lambda avoid recursive trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm downloading data from an API and writing it to a csv file that I store in an S3 bucket. I'm then copying my file from this input bucket into an output bucket with a Lambda function. From the output bucket I'm ingesting it into a MySQL RDS instance with another Lambda function.

The copy-to-another-bucket and upload-to-RDS lambda functions both get triggered when I create a new object in a bucket. Since I'm appending to my csv file, the upload-to-RDS function gets triggered way more than it should and I end up with ~30 rows in my database instead of 6.

I thought by copying the files between S3 buckets I could avoid this, but it doesn't help. Is there any way to only upload the csv file to the database once it has been written and not while it's being updated? Can I delay the trigger maybe?

The only other solution I can think of is to skip the copy-to-another-bucket function altogether and to schedule the upload-to-RDS function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to realize that S3 doesn't support updating an existing file. If you are appending a row to an existing CSV file in S3, then that operation requires uploading the entire contents of the CSV file to S3 again, which S3 sees as a new object.

If you need to store a temporary version of the CSV file in S3 while you are updating it, then you should store it in a separate path, like `s3://your_bucket/tmp` and then when you have completed your updates, move it to the final path like `s3://your_bucket/complete` and only configure the Lambda trigger on the `/complete` path.